# React node js contact form error 404 in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've made a contact form for my react app that works on localhost but once I deploy it doesn't work anymore. Been trying different url for post, with or without port but each time it throws an error.

As it is now I get this in the console:

> Error: Request failed with status code 404 at e.exports (createError.js:16)
> at e.exports (settle.js:17)
> at XMLHttpRequest.x (xhr.js:66)

This is how I submit the mail:

```
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://url.com/send',
            data: formData
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.data.status === 'success') {
                toast.success(
                    <div>
                        Success
                    </div>
                );
                resetForm();
            } else if (response.data.status === 'fail') {
                toast.error(
                    <div>
                        Error
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });
```

This is my server:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

app.use(express.static('build'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    req.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

var transport = {
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'my_email@gmail.com',
        pass: 'my_password'
    }
};
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport);

transporter.verify((error, success) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Server is ready to take messages');
    }
});

router.post('/send', (req, res, next) => {
    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
    var subject = req.body.subject;
    var message = req.body.message;
    var dataConsent = req.body.dataConsent;

    var content = `Name:\n${
        firstName + ' ' + lastName
    }\n\n\nEmail:\n${email}\n\n\nPhone Number:\n${phoneNumber}\n\n\nSubject:\n${subject}\n\n\nMessage:\n${message}\n\n\nConsent:\n${dataConsent}`;

    var mail = {
        from: email,
        to: 'test@gmail.com',
        subject: subject,
        text: content
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mail, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                status: 'fail'
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                status: 'success'
            });
        }
    });
});

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(3002);
```

And in package.json I run this script on start:

```
    "start": "node src/server.js",
```

Comment: if you have setup the nginx.conf/apache.conf file, please add here i think its possible that issue is in nginx.conf/apache.conf file

Comment: I don't have nginx/apache, I'm using only what I've listed. Should I add that? It's the first time I deploy a backend for react and I'm out of the loop

Comment: Would you please tell me production means where you have deployed this code ?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing it out on netlify before I deploy it to the shared host

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express(); // app comes after express require
var cors = require('cors');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
app.use(express.static('build'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  req.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

var transport = {
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'my_email@gmail.com',
    pass: 'my_password',
  },
};
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transport);

transporter.verify((error, success) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } else {
    console.log('Server is ready to take messages');
  }
});

router.post('/contact',async (req, res, next) => {
  var firstName = req.body.firstName;
  var lastName = req.body.lastName;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
  var subject = req.body.subject;
  var message = req.body.message;
  var dataConsent = req.body.dataConsent;

  var content = `Name:\n${
    firstName + ' ' + lastName
  }\n\n\nEmail:\n${email}\n\n\nPhone Number:\n${phoneNumber}\n\n\nSubject:\n${subject}\n\n\nMessage:\n${message}\n\n\nConsent:\n${dataConsent}`;

  var mail = {
    from: email,
    to: 'test@gmail.com',
    subject: subject,
    text: content,
  };

 const info = await transporter.sendMail(mail);
  
 return res.send({info});
});
// const app = express();  app is executed in wrong place
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(3002);
```

You have made mistakes this file. `const app = express();` comes after `var express = require('express');`

Comment: Now switched to net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: I have updated the response please do check